# Unable to resolve entry in hosts file?

Tags: linux, hosts, resolv.conf

I have the following entry in the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 postgres
```

This works most of the time:

```
[root@l25 log]# ping postgres
PING postgres (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.020 ms
```

Sometimes, apparently at random, a number of my services report they can't resolve it:

```
Failed to submit event: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: System error
```

In fact they can't resolve any other hosts as well:

```
Unable to record event with remote Sentry server (Errno::EBUSY - Failed to open TCP connection to xxx.ingest.sentry.io:443 (Device or resource busy - getaddrinfo)):
```

Rebooting the machine solves the problem for some time, then it starts showing up again.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Are you using a dns caching daemon such as nscd?

Comment: No sir nothing like that. Plain vanilla CentOS 7 install on linode.

Comment: When that happens, can you still resolve host names on the console? `ping postgres`, `host www.google.com`, `getent hosts www.google.com`?

Comment: Most of the time I can. But the web application/its services sometimes cannot. Maybe 1 out of 1000-5000 requests fails. It's like something blocks the resolver sometimes. Fresh out of the logs: [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] Error performing ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: ...) from Sidekiq(mailers) in 67.35ms: Errno::EBUSY (Device or resource busy - getaddrinfo)

Comment: This may be somehow related to fail2ban. I had it running so I can block lame script kiddie web app scans. As soon as I stopped fail2ban the errors disappeared. Still investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by having only 4096 inotify handlers. I've increased the limits and the issue is gone.

```
fs.file-max = 131070
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 65536
```